# How to add new file to config/initializers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have added a new file in `config/initializers` `my_app.rb`

and added the following code to it:

`MyApp.config.params_name = {:key_1 => "value"}`

I' getting this error uninitialized constant MyApp (NameError)

any Idea !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `module MyApp` defined in your application.rb.

Comment: Try Rails.application.config.params_name instead.